# What does it do? webkit-font-smoothing

Tags: css, fonts, webkit

So as the title suggest what does the webkit-font-smoothing do? I've used this in my CSS for multiple projects but what does it actually do?

I'm going to guess it has something to do with the font but what does it do exactly; I've removed it from the CSS multiple but it doesn't seem to affect anything. Does it only work on certain browsers? Like older ones or something?

My Questions:

- What does it do?
- Does it affect anything?
- Do you really need it?

I'm using the latest Chrome Version

I appreciate the feedback on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webkit-font-smoothing > antialiased your fonts display
test your code with this ligne :) beuarkkkk...

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: none;
```

Comment: Hmmm.... is there anywhere to read upon on what it does in detail? I wanna know if it affects anything? Do you need it? Stuff like that

Comment: look this page for example -> http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing